# best practice for initializing class members in php

Tags: php, oop, class, constructor, initialization

I have lots of code like this in my constructors:-

```
function __construct($params) {

    $this->property = isset($params['property']) ? $params['property'] : default_val;

}
```

Some default values are taken from other properties, which was why I was doing this in the constructor. But I guess it could be done in a setter instead.

What are the pros and cons of this method and is there a better one?

**Edit:** I have some dependencies where if a property is not supplied in the `$params` array then the value is taken from another property, however that other property may be optional and have a default value, so the order in which properties are initialized matters.

This means that if I used getters and setters then it is not obvious which order to call them in because the dependencies are abstracted away in the getter instead of being in the constructer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create "globally available" function `array_get`.

```
public static function array_get($array, $property, $default_value = null) {
    return isset($array[$property]) ? $array[$property] : $default_value;
}
```

Comment: The question was about setting not getting :)

Comment: `$this->property = Misc::array_get($params, 'property', 'default');` and now you are setting.

Comment: Actually that's pretty neat for abstracting away all of the `$var = () ? : ;` statements - I think I'll probably incorporate that into my current method. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you, to write proper getter/setter functions, which assert you the correct data-type and validations (and contain your mentioned default-value logic). Those should be used inside your constructor.
When setting multiple fields, which depend on each other, it seems to be nice to have a separate setter for this complex data. In which kind of way are they depending anyway?

e.g.:

```
// META-Config
protected $static_default_values = array(
  "price" => 0.0,
  "title" => "foobar"
  // and so on
);

protected $fallback_getter = array(
  "price" => "getfallback_price"
);


// Class Logic
public function __construct($params){
  $this->set_properties($params);
}

public set_properties($properties){
  // determines the sequence of the setter-calls
  $high_prio_fields = array("price", "title", "unimportant_field");

  foreach($high_prio_fields as $field){
    $this->generic_set($field, $properties[$field]);
    // important: unset fields in properties-param to avoid multiple calls
    unset($properties[$field]);
  }

  foreach($properties as $field => $value){
    $this->generic_set($field, $value);
  }
}

// this could also be defined within the magic-setter,
// but be aware, that magic-functions can't be resolved by your IDE completely
// for code-completion!
private function generic_set($field, $value){
  // check if setter exists for given field-key
   $setter_func = "set_".$v;
   if(method_exists($this, $setter_func){
     call_user_func_array(array($this, $setter_func), array($v));
   }
   // else => just discard  :)        
}

// same comment as generic-set
private function generic_get($field){
  // check if value is present in properties array
  if(isset($this->properties[$field]){
    return $this->properties[$field];
  }

  // check if fallback_getter is present
  if(isset($this->fallback_getter[$field]){
    return  call_user_func_array(array($this, $this->fallback_getter[$field]));
  }

  // check for default-value in meta-config
  if(isset($this->static_default_values[$field]){
    return $this->static_default_values[$field];
  }

  // else => fail (throw exception or return NULL)
  return null;
}


public function get_price(){
  // custom getter, which ovverrides generic get (if you want to)
  // custom code...
  return $this->generic_get("price");
}

private function getfallback_price(){
  return $this->properties["other_value"] * $this->properties["and_another_value"];
}

public function set_price($price){
  $price = (float) $price; // convert to correct data-type
  if($price >= 0.0){
    $this->properties["price"] = $price;
  }
  // else discard setting-func, because given parameter seems to be invalid
  // optional: throw exception or return FALSE on fail (so you can handle this on your own later)
}
```

**Update to your edit:**
the modified source-code should solve all your demands (order of setter-funcs, different resolvings of get-value).

Comment: This method would be problematic with some of the dependencies I have, see my edit above

Comment: the modified source-code should solve all your demands (order of setter-funcs, different resolvings of get-value).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think for now I am going to KISS and stick with my current method. Getters and setters seem like an enormous amount of code by comparison and I'm not sure the benefits are worth the investment until we start running into problems with the current method.

Comment: You're welcome. But be aware those generic getters and setters are most qualified to be implemented inside a superclass and all your models should extend it. Seems to be much code at first sight, but it is *that* code you don't have to implement over and over again along your model-classes. You just have to add code/methods in future, which differ from your default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

When having a lot of default options and you need to be able to overwrite them - as you have maybe seen in jQuery using `.extend()` before - I like to use this simple and quick method:

```
class Foo {
    private $options;

    public function __construct($override = array()) {
        $defaults = array(
           'param1' => 'foo', 
           'param2' => ..., 
           'paramN' => 'someOtherDefaultValue');
        $this->options= array_replace_recursive($defaults, $override);
    }
}
```

Especially for getting classes started this is a very easy and flexible way, but as already has been mentioned if that code is going to be heavily used then it probably not a bad idea to introduce some more control over those options with getters and setters, especially if you need to take actions when some of those options are get or set, like in your case dependencies if I understood your problem correctly.

Also note that you don't have to implement getters and setters yourself, in PHP you can use the __get and __set magic methods.

It follows some useless code that hopefully gives some ideas:

```
[...inside Foo...]
public function __set($key, $value){
    switch(true){
        //option exists in this class
        case isset($this->options[$key]):
           //below check if $value is callable
           //and use those functions as "setter" handlers
           //they could resolve dependencies for example 
           $this->options[$key] = is_callable($value) ? $value($key) : $value;  
        break;
        //Adds a virtual setter to Foo. This so called 'magic' __set method is also called if the property doesn't exist in the class, so you can add arbitrary things.
        case $key === 'someVirtualSetterProp': Xyzzy::Noop($value); break;
        default: 
           try{ parent::__set($key, $value); } catch(Exception $e){ /* Oops, fix it! */ }
    }
}
```

Note that in the above examples I squeezed in different approaches and it usually doesn't make sense to mix them like that. I did this only to illustrate some ideas and hopefully you will be able to decide better what suits your needs.

Comment: The first method you suggest is pretty much exactly how I am currently doing it (I simplified the code for my question). I'm not so keen on using magic methods, IMO they make the code less readable. I think I'll probably stick with my current method for now and maybe if there is time at the end of the project I can refactor and add getters and setters.